# Get database record automatically at a specific time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a task that basically I don't know how to accomplish it and I want some advice from you guys : I have a database that contains many binary images and a website that has a button.

When I press it a `select` statement is executed to search all the newly inserted rows after a specific date and send it to the website to process. My boss asked me if there is any way I can do that process manually by using a web service or anything else like a trigger in the database that automatically searches for new rows after a specific date and sends the new rows to the web site.

I don't know if I explained what I need. My main question is it possible to do this and what is the best way to achieve it. one more thing if it is achievable can I trigger it to work every day at a specific time ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you question, these are the requirements:

- You need to automate the process that is now manually triggered by clicking the button on the web page

The simplest way to do this in my opinion would be to create a small `Console application` and install it on a suitable server. Then on the server create a `Windows task scheduler` (Google it unless you're already familiar with it) task that runs the console application on a suitable schedule.

You could for instance have it run once every night at say 10 minutes past midnight and it would fetch all images from the past day and "*send them to be processed*".

Comment: and the console application should contain the select statement that fetch all the new record from the database ? and send it to the website ?

Comment: @Sora Whatever is done on the web server when the button is clicked should instead be done in the console application. It's however unclear to me what *send it to the website to process* actually means... What kind of processing is happening? Could the actual processing also be done in the console application?

Comment: i mean that in the current scenario their is a c# function that convert the binary images sent from the DB to images and show them to the client on the web that what i mean by send it to the website to process :)

Comment: @Sora In that case my answer makes absolutely no sense. I'll probably delete it later on. After all, how could you send an image to be displayed in a web browser unless someone is actually browsing the site in a browser? Please update your question with a better description of what is currently happening and what you would want to happen instead.

Comment: no your answer is the right answer what i will do is to get the binary image and convert it into a real image and save it under the website directory than from the website i'll read the directory and display it and that should work i guess

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand website is not a repository of records but it works based on user requests. So in your website if you want to change contents on web pages, try AJAX reqeusts. If you are looking for some options to update details in other systems periodically think of eitehr Windows services,  or cron jobs or may be SSIS jobs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cursor and Trigger but u have to store date in database which u want display on particular date